# Record Browser Actions

Tags: browser

I am looking for some browser recording software which can record browser actions for one of the business application and give the html elements :- name/id/xpath of the element along with the action performed (ex click, send keys, javascript etc)

My "application under test" is specific to IE and it doesn't run in any other browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). It allows you to record browser actions and save them for later use (like automated browser testing).

You may want to try using [SeleniumRC](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) if you want to do this for Internet Explorer. You'll still have to set up some steps through firefox, but you should be able to run your tests on IE.

Comment: Isn't Selenium recording works only for Firefox? My "application under test" is specific to IE and it doesn't run in any other browser.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry about that. Are you strictly trying to record browser actions or are you trying to drive the browser as well?

Comment: I want to record the browser action and at the end it should give me the list of HTML elements on which User has performed actions (in a script file or so). ex - <Tag name or id=UserName /> action=sendkeys

Answer (score 0):

Try out contizee (www.contizee.com)  which is a browser based plug in, easy record and playback and allows me to edit action paths e.g.

```
$("input#fk-top-search-box").val("HP COMPAQ"); 
form#fk-header-search-form>div.search-bar-wrap>div.search-bar>div.unit.search-bar-submit-wrap.size1of6>input.search-bar-submit.fk-font-13.fk-font-bold
```

We can customize according to our needs

Comment: The website that you provided does not seem to render.